# Read file and store each line as a different variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble storing each line as a separate variable. I understand how to read a file and parse each line but I am having trouble storing them separately.

```
def setOffsets():
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://blahblahblah.net/file.txt")
for line in data:
```

The file would contain data like this:

```
1234
4321
1234
```

Is there anyway possible to have line 1 stored as x, line 2 stored as y and so on? I looked at other methods and they store the data as lists and arrays which I am simply not interested in. I am only dealing with a few lines.

Comment: Why aren't you interested in lists?  That is the best way to do it.  If you know that there will be only three lines, you can do `x, y, z = data.readlines()`, but if it is an unknown number of lines, you shouldn't define a new variable for each line.

Comment: Indent your code and add what's missing under `for line in data:` if anything. Also, why assume that a list or dictionary is only meant for storing numerous items? Anything that keeps you from writing `var1 = "a", var2 = "b", var3 = "c", ...` is a better option. Generally, it's a good idea to adhere to the principle of "DRY" / **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself

Comment: well, it isn't really that simple, from my understanding atleast. I am  using ctypes.wintypes and need the file contents stored as DWORD. I am pretty new to this so I am not really sure.

Comment: x,y,z=[1,2,4]

    x,y,z=(1,2,4)

Comment: @Scheming When you read file contents in Python, you're implicitly working with Python's datatypes that are not C-datatypes. I think you'd need to cast/convert your strings using some C-datatype module if you want to turn strings like "1234" into DWORDS/32 bit unsigned integers. Perhaps that's what ctypes.wintypes does, I don't know.

Comment: Do you want each string such as `"1234\n"` read from a line in the file to be converted to the the numeric value `1234` so you can store it in a DWORD?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), `urlopen()` returns a file-like object. Hence, methods such as `readline()` (returns the next line) and `readlines()` (returns a list of all lines as bytestrings) are available:

```
x, y, z = data.readlines()  # as pointed out in the comments by @zondo

# equivalent, but more robust if more lines than wanted are present
x = data.readline()
y = data.readline()
z = data.readline()
```

Comment: But isn't this basically pointless although it's what OP requests? It's still just the same strings or bytes that would/should normally be stored in a list or dictionary, right?

Comment: Absolutely true. But, as you point out, the OP wants to store lines to individually named variables directly (let's not question motives) and there's the way to do it.

Comment: Sure, I get that but what if OP''s proposed methods are not conducive to his/her motives?